# How to prove that a variable can be defined implicitly from an equation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given the equation $xe^z + ye^{-z} + z = 1$, define $z$ implicitly at $A \times [0,\infty)$ as a function of $(x,y)$.

Where
$$
A = \{(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1] \mid x+y \leq 1\}
$$

---

I don’t know how to prove that a function define implicitly a variable, because implicitly means that i can’t derive $z=...$, i dont see what should i prove here... and how.

Can someone give me a direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you fix the notation?  I have a hard time telling what you're even asking.

Comment: Where is the problem with the notations? @JohnSamples

Comment: I've fixed it, give it a moment for the edit to go through.

Comment: You can see implicit function theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem